# How do you filter by passing a string as a column name in a user-defined function?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, rlang, curly-braces

I'm writing a function where the user specifies the column they want to filter and what cutoff value they want. In this example, I want to filter out any pretest scores under 2. Here's a sample dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

test <- tibble(name = c("Corey", "Justin", "Sibley", "Kate"),
               pretest_score = c(1:4),
               posttest_score = c(5:8),
               final_score = c(9:12))


filter_function <- function(data, test_type = c(pretest, posttest, final), value) {
  
  test_character <- deparse(substitute(test_type))
  test_score <- paste0(test_character, "_score")
  
  data %>%
    filter({{test_score}} > value)
  
}

filter_function(test, test_type = pretest, value = 2)
```

I've also tried !!test_score, test_score (with nothing around it), and ensym(test_score) from `rlang`, all to no avail.

Note: I know that in *this* example, I could just specify pretest_score, posttest_score, etc as the test type, but in my real dataset, I have many dimensions for these tests that users can determine cutoffs for (pretest_score, pretest_date, pretest_location, etc.), so **it's important that I merge the column prefix with the suffix (here, _score) within the function itself.**

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the character to `sym`bol and evaluate with `!!`

```
filter_function <- function(data, test_type = c(pretest, posttest, 
      final), value) {
  
  test_character <- deparse(substitute(test_type))
  test_score <- paste0(test_character, "_score")
  
  data %>%
    filter(!! rlang::sym(test_score) > value)
  
}
```

-testing

```
> filter_function(test, test_type = pretest, value = 2)
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  name   pretest_score posttest_score final_score
  <chr>          <int>          <int>       <int>
1 Sibley             3              7          11
2 Kate               4              8          12
```

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

- normally when a set of options are used in R one uses a character vector, not an unevaluated expression.  R specifically provides `match.arg` for this purpose.  This also implements a default of the first option so if we use `match.arg` the call invoking the function could have omitted `type_test = "pretest"` as that is the default.
- `.[[test_score]]` can be used to specify the indicated column

Thus we have

```
filter_function <- function(data, test_type = c("pretest", "posttest", "final"), 
  value) {

  test_type <- match.arg(test_type)
  test_score <- paste0(test_type, "_score")
  
  data %>%
    filter(.[[test_score]] > value)
  
}

filter_function(test, test_type = "pretest", value = 2)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  name   pretest_score posttest_score final_score
  <chr>          <int>          <int>       <int>
1 Sibley             3              7          11
2 Kate               4              8          12

# pretest is the default
filter_function(test, value = 2)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  name   pretest_score posttest_score final_score
  <chr>          <int>          <int>       <int>
1 Sibley             3              7          11
2 Kate               4              8          12
```

Also note that we could specify the function like this.  The user can still specify "pretest" since `match.arg` will match the leading substring.  In fact they could even specify "pre" or "post".

```
filter_function2 <- function(data, 
    test_type = c("pretest_score", "posttest_score", "final_score"), 
    value) {

  test_type <- match.arg(test_type)
  
  data %>%
    filter(.[[test_type]] > value)
  
}

filter_function2(test, test_type = "pretest", value = 2)
```

### Base R

This could also be done without any packages like this:

```
filter_function3 <- function(data, test_type = c("pretest", "posttest", "final"), 
  value) {

  test_type <- match.arg(test_type)
  test_score <- paste0(test_type, "_score")
  
  data[data[[test_score]] > value, ]

}

filter_function3(test, test_type = "pretest", value = 2)
```